# Two Given Names

Tags: customs-and-immigration

My Philippine birth certificate shows two given names, middle name, and family name. However, since my schools days I used only one given name. My Philippine passport and other government issued identification cards shows only my first given name, middle name, and family name.  Will there be a problem if my son petitions me to live in the United States?

Comment: it is very common to have further - mostly unused - given names, so no worries.